# How do I XPath to attribute whose namespace is different to its ancestor's

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to query the codebase attribute on line 11 of this XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xrml="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
    <assemblyIdentity name="VcilApp.application" version="0.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
    <description asmv2:publisher="VCIL" asmv2:product="VcilApp" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
    <deployment install="true" minimumRequiredVersion="0.0.0.0" co.v1:createDesktopShortcut="true">
        <subscription>
            <update>
                <beforeApplicationStartup />
            </update>
        </subscription>
        <deploymentProvider codebase="file://vandc/vcfileshare/VC Apps/Dialler/VcilApp.application" />
    </deployment>
    <compatibleFrameworks xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
        <framework targetVersion="4.5" profile="Full" supportedRuntime="4.0.30319" />
    </compatibleFrameworks>
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="Application Files\VcilApp_3_0_9_2705\VcilApp.exe.manifest" size="26738">
            <assemblyIdentity name="VcilApp.exe" version="0.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" type="win32" />
            <hash>
                <dsig:Transforms>
                    <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
                </dsig:Transforms>
                <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
                <dsig:DigestValue>7ikkD3Ls5FCfLulntbYd54jZwk/4L5dnNZ4rGBZELB8=</dsig:DigestValue>
            </hash>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

It need to be something along the lines of /assembly/deployment/deploymentProvider/@codebase but the namespace prefixes need to be accounted for. The deployment element is possibly causing the problem as it's not in the asmv1 namespace like its ancestors.

Can anyone provide an xpath to the codebase attribute?

Comment: If you could make a more human-readable XML sample to demonstrate the problem, it would be great.

Comment: @Lev sorry I'm struggling to do that with SO editor. I've uploaded it here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/635601/VcilApp.application

Comment: You have to add all namespaces from xml to your stylesheet and than use the prefixes you are assigned to them (may differ from xml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't give us the details of in what context you will use the XPath expression, but generally:

1. Map `asmv1` to `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1`
2. Map `asmv2` to `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2`

then this expression will get you what you want:

```
/asmv1:assembly/asmv2:deployment/asmv2:deploymentProvider/@codebase
```